# How to edit my CSS to control footer menu styling?

Tags: css

I am working on a site

dev.pfp-consortium.org

For the footer menu I have an id footermenu. I thought I could do the following to style it, but it is not working:

```
#footermenu ul li a{
color: #b3d1ff;
}
#footermenu ul li a:hover{
color: #ffffff;
}
```

Any ideas? I am fairly new to CSS and all these inheritance relationships get confusing, as well as syntax. Thanks!

Comment: The syntax seems to be fine and it's working for me, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: Add the footer HTML also to the question.

Comment: can u show your footer HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way :

```
#footermenu li a{ color: #b3d1ff; }
```

**OR**

```
ul#footermenu li a{ color: #b3d1ff; }
```

Answer (score 1):

`footermenu` is the id to the `ul` so `#footermenu ul` means you want a ul inside a container with id `footermenu`

Use this

```
ul#footermenu li a{
color: #b3d1ff;
}
ul#footermenu li a:hover{
color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! that worked! I wish I understood the logic more (i.e. why my syntax was not working), but I guess it is just a question of time!

Comment: @Brian: search **css selectors** - you'll find out a lot of info is already available

Comment: @Brian Happy to help :). If you are satisfied with the answer you can accept and update the answer. [How to accept answer (Ignore this if you know how to)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers)

Answer (score 0):

try this.,

```
ul#footermenu li a{
color: #b3d1ff;
}
ul#footermenu li a:hover{
color: #ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want the new style over the old inherited you should set `!important` like:

```
color: #ffffff !important;
```

Comment: this seams to be a problem with the order of the css (`#footermenu` is the id of the `ul`) not with `!important`